# How to use helm chart deploy a .net 6 worker service?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, .net-6.0

I have a .net 6 MVC program and a Worker Service program. they work in both local environment and on AKS if I deploy them with a "Deployment" yaml file. But when I try creating a helm chart and deploy them, only the MVC program works. The Worker Service doesn't. When I run the chart with "dry-run", it doesn't even generate the Deployment yaml for the Worker Service, only MVC Deployment and Service get generated.

```
helm upgrade --install my-release . --dry-run
```

here is the value.yaml I created for the helm chart

```
#this is the MVC section
corewebmvc:
  replicaCount: 1

  image:
    repository: t3odeqiclinkacr01.azurecr.io/corewebmvc
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    tag: "v1.0.0"

  nodeSelector: 
    "kubernetes.io/os": linux

  service:
    type: LoadBalancer
    port: 80

  ingress:
    enabled: false

  serviceAccount:
    create: false

  autoscaling:
    enabled: false

#this is the Worker Service section
corewkrsvc:
  replicaCount: 1

  image:
    repository: t3odeqiclinkacr01.azurecr.io/corewkrsvc
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    tag: "v1.0.0"

  nodeSelector: 
    "kubernetes.io/os": linux

  service: QLWkrSvc

  ingress:
    enabled: false

  serviceAccount:
    create: false

  autoscaling:
    enabled: false
```

I am completely new to helm, so if anyone can show me what I am doing wrong here, it will be highly appreciated.

**UPDATE**
I created the chart by following [this article](https://andrewlock.net/deploying-asp-net-core-applications-to-kubernetes-part-4-creating-a-helm-chart-for-an-aspnetcore-app/) . Here is my chart folder
[image]

and here is the templates/deployment.yaml file for the Worker Service chart

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "corewkrsvc.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    {{- include "corewkrsvc.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
spec:
  {{- if not .Values.autoscaling.enabled }}
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  {{- end }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      {{- include "corewkrsvc.selectorLabels" . | nindent 6 }}
  template:
    metadata:
      {{- with .Values.podAnnotations }}
      annotations:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      labels:
        {{- include "corewkrsvc.selectorLabels" . | nindent 8 }}
    spec:
      {{- with .Values.imagePullSecrets }}
      imagePullSecrets:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      serviceAccountName: {{ include "corewkrsvc.serviceAccountName" . }}
      securityContext:
        {{- toYaml .Values.podSecurityContext | nindent 8 }}
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          securityContext:
            {{- toYaml .Values.securityContext | nindent 12 }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag | default .Chart.AppVersion }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: http
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: http
          resources:
            {{- toYaml .Values.resources | nindent 12 }}
      {{- with .Values.nodeSelector }}
      nodeSelector:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      {{- with .Values.affinity }}
      affinity:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      {{- with .Values.tolerations }}
      tolerations:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
```

**UPDATE-1**

further testing show that the problem seems to be relate to the "service" entry for the Worker Serive in the value.yaml file.

```
  service: QLWkrSvc
```

There is an error related to the line above - "Error: UPGRADE FAILED: template: tpa-poc/charts/corewkrsvc/templates/service.yaml:8:18: executing "tpa-poc/charts/corewkrsvc/templates/service.yaml" at <.Values.service.type>: can't evaluate field type in type interface {}"

If I remove the above line from value.yaml, I get error "Error: UPGRADE FAILED: template: tpa-poc/charts/corewkrsvc/templates/service.yaml:8:18: executing "tpa-poc/charts/corewkrsvc/templates/service.yaml" at <.Values.service.type>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.type" instead.

So looks like I need to have the service entry in there, but with what value (type) then?

Comment: What helm does is help you package your deployment files into a template, you need to have a templates folder with your equivalent template yaml files that helm would then substitute with values  from the values folder. Could you share files in your templates/ folder?

Comment: Please see my updates above. I only rewrote the value.yaml and didn't change much of anything else, except some program names in other files.

Comment: Could you add a --debug flag at the end of helm upgrade --install my-release . --dry-run to see the output

Comment: You said you have two programs; do you also have two matching `templates/*-deployment.yaml` files?  (And probably also two matching Services?)

Comment: I do have two deployment.yaml, each for its own program chart. But I have only one Service - the one for MVC program, as that's the only one will be accessed by external parties. The Worker Service program is server program that runs on the backgroud or a Daemon, in Linux termers.

Comment: Maybe I need to have a service for Worker Service as well? But with what type?

Comment: see my update above - I guess the problem is that I am not having the right service value for the Worker Service program in the value.yaml. But I still can't figure out what value/format to use.